# Computer boots up but is completely unresponsive

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard, power-supply, sleep

I have had my computer for 2 years and it has worked completely fine up until yesterday.
I installed the latest update (21.1.1) to my AMD Radeon software and restarted my computer to apply the changes. After logging back in after restarting, I got another prompt asking me to restart to install a hardware update. Past this, the computer bricked. It will boot up and give me the green light on the front but no signal is going to my keyboard, mouse, or monitor.

Due to this, I cannot enter bios to revert whatever update occurred. At first, I thought it was a GPU issue, but after installing a separate gpu and getting no signal again, I moved my suspicion to the motherboard. I cannot tell specifically if the motherboard or power supply are dying, but I can say that neither are dead.

At this point, I believe my computer somehow found its way into a state of perpetual hibernation and nothing I do can get it out of that. Usually, I will press the power button to bring the computer out of hibernation, but it does nothing in this case.

Things I've tried:
Removing ram, booting, powering off, inserting ram, booting again
Removing cmos battery and running the same sequence
Holding power for 20+ seconds
Removing power supply, ram, and repeating sequence
Removing all but the ram, motherboard, power supply, and cpu
Replacing the ram with a new Corsair 8gb one
Removing all but the motherboard, power supply, and cpu

The only things I know left to try are a different gpu and a different motherboard.

If helpful, my specs are:

- Ryzen 5 2400g
- Radeon RX 580
- Unknown motherboard
- 8gb Corsair ram
- Windows 10 (updated last Thursday)
- Unknown power supply

This is a prebuilt computer.

**Edit:**
I believe I have ruled out it being just stalled on sleep mode as I removed my boot drives and booted the computer and still got nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost guaranteed it is a bricked motherboard as, with just the motherboard, cpu, and power supply, there was 0 power to any usb port, although there was power to the cpu and fans.

Comment: It might have been interesting to examine the system logs found on the drive using another system. As it seems the failing of the board and the installation was just an unlucky coincidence. Maybe there were symptoms of a hardware problem earlier.

Answer (score -2):

The hardware installed is not compatible with the latest version of the software. you installed, so reinstall the previous software version for the system to get repaired automatically.

Comment: I cannot get into the computer. I would be able to fix it of I could get in